IUPLua, can't change button color and can't add Image
I'm trying to change the color of a button, which doesn't seem to work, aswell as adding an Image.
For the Image:
I tried doing it with the IUPweb browser so it could load the image, it worked, however I dont really like that it still got the sidebar etc. so that's no option.
Also tried iup.LoadImage but it didn't work for me either.
I preferebly use the iamges with links, however if there's no other option I can use Image Files also
require("iuplua")

local screenWidth, screenHeight = 1920, 1080
local windowWidth = screenWidth * 0.4
local windowHeight = screenHeight * 0.3

local Data = {
    ["Industrialist"] = {
        Image = "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg",
        ID = "9192423027"
    },
    ["Engineer"] = {
        Image = "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg",
        ID = "9192423027"
    },
    ["Scientist"] = {
        Image = "https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg",
        ID = "9192423027"
    },
}

local Instances = {}

function createInstance(Title, Data)
    local label = iup.label{
        title = Title,
        alignment = "ACENTER",
        valign = "TOP", 
        halign = "CENTER",
        fgcolor = "255 255 255"
    }
    
    local button = iup.button{
        title = "Open",
        bgcolor = "2 183 87",--"#02b757"
        alignment = "ACENTER",
        size = "100x30",
        action = function()
            local link = "roblox://placeId=" .. Data.ID
            os.execute('start "" "' .. link .. '"')
        end
    }
    
    local Image = iup.label{image = iup.LoadImage("Images/Industrialist.png")}
    --THIS DID NOT WORK
    
    -- Creating the container for the components
    local container = iup.vbox{
        label,
        Image,
        button,
        alignment = "ACENTER",
        valign = "CENTER",
        halign = "CENTER",
        size = "150x200",
        expand = "YES"
    }
    
    return container
end

for i, v in pairs(Data) do
    table.insert(Instances, createInstance(i, v))
end

local gridBox = iup.gridbox{
    orientation = "HORIZONTAL",
    numdiv = 3,
    alignment = "ACENTER",
    expand = "YES",
    table.unpack(Instances)
}

local dlg = iup.dialog{
    gridBox,
    title = "Alchemister",
    size = windowWidth.."x"..windowHeight,
    bgcolor = "17 18 22",
    resize = "YES"
}

dlg:show()

iup.MainLoop()



The code is mostly working, I just added:
require("iupluaim")

So I believe you don have all the dependancies. IUP is not enough, you need the IM library.
You will need to link against:

The library IM itself, at least libim.a and libz.a
The Lua wrapper, for example libimlua54.a

Obviously, on the C side, iupimlua_open need to be called somewhere.

Yes, that's right. It needs the IUP-IM binding.
You you are dynamically loading with require it does not need any additional link. And iupimlua_open will automatically be called by require("iupluaim")

The native button has some limitations regarding the background color. See the BGCOLOR attribute documentation:

BGCOLOR: Background color. If text and image are not defined, the
button is configured to simply show a color, in this case set the
button size because the natural size will be very small. In Windows
and in GTK 3, the BGCOLOR attribute is ignored if text or image is
defined.

